# Is there a FEM package for R

Tags: r

I am looking for a R package that performs finite element analysis. Is there a fenics or equivalent FEM package for R?

Comment: what exactly do you want to use FEA for? R is not exactly the language of choice when it comes to FEM implementations. there is the [`fdaPDE` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fdaPDE/), but I'm not sure that's what you're looking for. see also this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996535/is-there-an-r-function-that-implements-the-finite-element-method)

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I am not trying to use R to solve fem type problems. I am looking for a fem package that can use R as a front end. I have used fdaPDE but it does not have the capabilities I need, such as a high level configuration language. I have tried installing fem-fenics which uses Octave as a front end, but installation fails due to a known problem with the required Dolphin package.